# Entity framework Querying

Tags: database, entity-framework

I am trying to figure out how to query my entities based on the following situation.

I have two tables, LKCATEGORY AND LKSUBCATEGORY as you can imagine this two tables are related to each other.  However when i come to a page that needs to display only active categories and subcategories how do i do this and pull back a list of LKCATEGORY with the LKSUBCATEGORY included in the reference with both of these filters in place(isActive = true on both entities).

My Repository call that pulls back a list of type LKCATEGORY looks like:

```
        //Create the Entity object
        List<LKCATEGORY> category = null;

            using (SOAE strikeOffContext = new SOAE())
            {
                //Invoke the query
                category = AdminDelegates.selectCategory.Invoke(strikeOffContext).ByActive(true).ToList();
            }
```

While the Delegate(selectCategory) looks like:

```
        public static Func<SOAE, IQueryable<LKCATEGORY>> selectCategory =
    CompiledQuery.Compile<SOAE, IQueryable<LKCATEGORY>>(
    (category) => from c in category.LKCATEGORY.Include("LKSUBCATEGORY")
                select c);
```

and finally the Filter(ByActive)

```
    public static IQueryable<LKCATEGORY> ByActive(this IQueryable<LKCATEGORY> qry, bool active)
    {
        //Return the filtered IQueryable object
        return from c in qry
               where c.ACTIVE == active
               select c;

    }
```

I realize i only have the filter on the LKCATEGORY entity and of course i would only be filtering that table.  My question is how do i filter both LKCATEGORY AND LKSUBCATEGORY and pull back a LIST of type LKCATEGORY with LKSUBCATEGORY included and filtered?

Thanks in advance,
Billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be your solution, but you can divide this into two queries and try this (I assume this is first operation on LKCATEGORY in context):

```
var categories = context.LKCATEGORY.Where(c => c.ACTIVE).ToList();
var subcategories = context.LKSUBCATEGORY.Where(c => c.ACTIVE).ToList();
return categories;
```

Now look at categories.LKSUBCATEGORY list and you'll see that you have only active ones. 
Other solution involves using linq `join` instead of `Include`.

**EDIT**

Alternative way:

```
context.LKCATEGORY.Where(c => c.ACTIVE).Select(c => new { Category = c, Subcategory = c.LKSUBCATEGORY.Where(sc => sc.ACTIVE) }).ToList().Select(a => a.Category);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I knew of another way to link the two with separate queries, but i like this one alot better.  Thanks.  If you have time please post your linq join example.  Thanks Again!
Billy